# How to count rows from one column with different value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a promblem to count rows from one column with different, here is my db and query

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'cbt';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

$matematika = 'MTK';
$soal_mtk = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from cbt.data_ujian where data_ujian.id_mapel = :mtk");
$soal_mtk->bindParam(':mtk', $matematika, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$soal_mtk->execute();
$mtk = $soal_mtk->fetchColumn();

$fisika = 'FIS';
$soal_fis = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from cbt.data_ujian where data_ujian.id_mapel = :fis");
$soal_fis->bindParam(':fis', $fisika, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$soal_fis->execute();
$fis = $soal_fis->fetchColumn();

$kimia = 'KIM';
$soal_kim = $pdo->prepare("select count(*) from cbt.data_ujian where data_ujian.id_mapel = :kim");
$soal_kim->bindParam(':kim', $kimia, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$soal_kim->execute();
$kim = $soal_kim->fetchColumn();
```

can i count all of that with one query?? please tell me if it need more information. Thankyou so much before.

Comment: Is there any relationship between cbt.data_ujian and data_user?

Comment: no there isn't. I just want to count mtk, fis and kim with one query

Comment: So what's the point of the table creation statements at the top of your question ?!?

Comment: I pasted it from my db

Comment: Cool. I just don't understand why.

Comment: in my previous experience there's someone ask for it to answer my question which literally has some similarity. sorry my bad english, thanks for editing my question.

Comment: Yes, if it was the table that featured in the query then I'd competely understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, You need to use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) with WHERE condition. Like this,

```
SELECT count(*),
       data_ujian.id_mapel
FROM cbt.data_ujian
WHERE (data_ujian.id_mapel = :mtk
       OR data_ujian.id_mapel = :fis
       OR data_ujian.id_mapel = :kim)
GROUP BY data_ujian.id_mapel
```

Above query will group the results by `id_mapel` column and give `count` from each of the category.

Comment: it appears that  the result is backward from id_mapel, it echo from the last id_mapel or rather i have fetch it the wrong but thankyou anyway.

Comment: See MySQL's `IN()` construct.

Comment: Yeah we can also use `IN()`

Comment: could you explain to me how to fetch id_mapel and count? i use foreach but it just printed the count or id_mapel.

Comment: The result you get from above query would be multidimensional array, which will be having two keys as  `group_name(id_mapel)` and `count` of that group. You can iterate over that array and display the count for each group.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right the GROUP BY clause should do what you ask for:

```
SELECT count(*), id_mapel FROM cbt.data_ujian GROUP BY id_mapel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query -

```
SELECT Sum(data_ujian.id_mapel = 'mtk') AS 'mtk', 
       Sum(data_ujian.id_mapel = 'fis') AS 'fis', 
       Sum(data_ujian.id_mapel = 'kim') AS 'kim', 
FROM   cbt.data_ujian;
```